# interface web-browser bot helper

Tags: python, browser, helper, bots

I have the interface with many controls which I need to set, the problem is that there are too many controls I need to set data in and click (whey work via ajax on https page). I want to write some helper which is integrated in my browser and do route clicking on certain page for me. It's Preferable to do this component with python. But I don't know how to start, how to do it in general terms? which libs preferably to use etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first try doing this with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). 
If the web page needs to execute javascript, you could

1. study the javascript to figure out
   what it does and mimick it with
   Python code (perhaps hard),
2. use [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/) or similar app
   to inspect headers and post
   parameters.
3. use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or similar app to
   inspect GET/POST requests. (Click on the Net>All buttons).
4. or use [SeleniumRC](http://seleniumhq.org/) to
   programmatically control your normal
   (javascript-capable) web browser.

Comment: mechanize is usually a good choice, but dealing with AJAX may require some work. At the end it depends on how the page works to decide if a browser-based module would be better suited.